# Could not parse remainder error while using ternary operator?

Tags: django, django-errors

**users.html**

```
<td><div class="form-group">
                         <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                           <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="user-{{i.id}}" {{(i.status) ? 'checked' : ' '}}
                              onclick="changeUserStatus(event.target, {{ i.id }});">
                           <label class="custom-control-label pointer"></label>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     </td>
```

why this error is showing?

```
Could not parse the remainder: '(i.status=='True') ? 'checked' : ''' from '(i.status=='True') ? 'checked' : '''
```

any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid syntax. Django templates do not have ternary operator. You can use {% if %} and {% else %}

Comment: you can also use built-in tag filter yesno , this is similar to if else statement in one line, take in consediration that the filter accept three arguement "True ,False , maybe" the third one used for None value

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing between python and javascript syntaxe , `id="user-{{i.id}}" {{(i.status) ? 'checked' : ' '}}` this is a javascript a syntaxe ,it worked for example in reactjs ,

for django template you can use **yesno** built in tag filter

```
           <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="user-{{i.id}}" {{ i.status |yesno:"checked,," }}
                        onclick="changeUserStatus(event.target, {{ i.id }});">
                     <label class="custom-control-label pointer"></label>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </td>
```

take a look in tag [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno)